# Vector to Raster conversion doesn't work with Point shapefiles (Python GDAL Library)

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, gdal-rasterize

```
def main1(shapefile):

    #making the shapefile as an object.
    input_shp = ogr.Open(shapefile)

    #getting layer information of shapefile.
    shp_layer = input_shp.GetLayer()

    #pixel_size determines the size of the new raster.
    #pixel_size is proportional to size of shapefile.
    pixel_size = 1

    #get extent values to set size of output raster.
    x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = shp_layer.GetExtent()

    #calculate size/resolution of the raster.
    x_res = int((x_max - x_min) / pixel_size)
    y_res = int((y_max - y_min) / pixel_size)

    #get GeoTiff driver by 
    image_type = 'GTiff'
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(image_type)

    #passing the filename, x and y direction resolution, no. of bands, new raster.
    new_raster = driver.Create(output_raster, x_res, y_res, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)

    #transforms between pixel raster space to projection coordinate space.
    new_raster.SetGeoTransform((x_min, pixel_size, 0, y_min, 0, pixel_size))

    #get required raster band.
    band = new_raster.GetRasterBand(1)

    #assign no data value to empty cells.
    no_data_value = -9999
    band.SetNoDataValue(no_data_value)
    band.FlushCache()

    #main conversion method
    gdal.RasterizeLayer(new_raster, [1], shp_layer, burn_values=[1])

    #adding a spatial reference
    new_rasterSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
    new_rasterSRS.ImportFromEPSG(2975)
    new_raster.SetProjection(new_rasterSRS.ExportToWkt())
    return gdal.Open(output_raster)
```

This is my code adapted from the *Python Geospatial Analysis Cookbook*. 
I'm trying to convert a vector .shp to a raster .tif. The code runs and works for line and polygon vector files, but for point shapefiles, it creates an empty black tif file.

Here is the input:
[image: input shapefile]

This is the output
[image: output raster]

So what changes do I make in the code so that it works for point shapefiles too?

Comment: Are you sure that the image is empty? Maybe you just do not see the single pixels which are the results of rasterization. Have you checked the image statistics or histogram if image contains any pixels with your burn value?